# "Angular 5+ bootstrap date & time picker" - Date Only

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

**Hi Community!**

I am Working with the following Date/Time-Picker:
https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.html

We use it on a Website several times in formulars to insert complexe Dates with Times, but now I need it in a special Case with the Date Only. To keep the Style of the Website I would like to use the same component as on the other tickers, but I am not able to configure this Component. Has anyone Experience with it and can tell me how this works?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `minView` to `day` as the documentation says:-

> If you want the end-user to select a only day (date), setting minView
>   to day will cause selection to happen when the end-user selects a cell
>   in the day view.

[Source of the documentation.](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/components/DlDateTimePickerComponent.html#minView)

Comment: Nice one, Thank you! :)